# regex multiple quotes selection

Tags: regex, string, double, quotes

I'm trying to extract sub strings out of one big string.
extracted sub strings should follow these rules:
1. between two double quote (e.g.: "hello \"jonathan\" how are you") would extract "jonathan" (without the double quotes).

1. same as 1, just with single quotes.
2. single quote is considered as a regular char when it's surrounded by double quotes. (e.g.: "Hello "Jonathan how 'are'" you today") would extract this sub string: "Jonathan how 'are'" -- without the double quotes.

I've been trying many combinations involving this pattern:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("([\"]*[\']*[\']*[\"])");
```

this one solves one issue (num 3), in this example:

```
String s = "Hello \"Jon\'hello\'athan\" how are 'you'"
```

It does extracts

```
Jon'hello'athan
```

but when I add something like:

```
([\'])|[\"])
```

to the pattern, it treats it like the whole pattern was

```
([\'])|[\"])
```

what would you recommend ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't need to deal with escaped quotes, and as long as all your quotes are correctly balanced, you can make use of a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(['"])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1
```

or, in Java:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(['\"])((?:(?!\\1).)*)\\1");
```

**Explanation:**

```
(['"])   # Match any quote character, capture it in group 1
(        # Match and capture in group 2:
 (?:     # Start of non-capturing group that matches...
  (?!\1) #  (as long as it's not the same quote character as in group 1)
  .      # ...any character
 )*      # any number of times.
)        # End of capturing group 2
\1       # Match the same quote as before
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/aL0jS9).

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast.
It didn't work for me actually...

this is what I get when I run this:

    Jon'hello'athan" i would like to

Comment: @user3454745: You need to take the second group of the `Matcher` object (after performing a `.find()` on it): `myMatcher.group(2)` will contain `Jon'hello'athan`.